# How to automatically redirect to custom admin menu after plugin activation?

Tags: plugins, plugin-options

I need a function to redirect user to the plugin settings page, right after plugin activation.

I use this function to create a custom menu settings page:

```
// add option page menu link
function axl_ads_add_admin_menu() { 
    $icon = 'dashicons-align-left"';
      add_menu_page( 'AXL Ads', 'AXL Ads', 'manage_options', 'axl_ads',  array($this, 'axl_ads_options_page'), $icon, '3' );
  }
```

And my settings page url is: `wp-admin/admin.php?page=axl_ads`

Any help with this, please?

Comment: Is this a plugin your coding or one you downloaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [register_activation_hook()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/). Add this to your plugin, tested and works.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'redirect_after_activation');

function redirect_after_activation() {
    add_option('redirect_after_activation_option', true);
}

add_action('admin_init', 'activation_redirect');

function activation_redirect() {
    if (get_option('redirect_after_activation_option', false)) {
        delete_option('redirect_after_activation_option');
        exit(wp_redirect(admin_url( 'wp-admin/admin.php?page=axl_ads' )));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a hook named register_activation_hook that usually works at the time of the plugin activation. This function should be called within the plugins_loaded hook. So,

Firstly, call the activation hook -

```
function fn_name(){
register_activation_hook(__FILE__,'activation_fn');
}
add_action('plugins_loaded','fn_name');
```

Now, you need to call the function -

```
function activation_fn(){
 wp_redirect($target_url);
}
```

here, wp_redirect($url) is used that redirect you to a specific location. So, simply add your target URL inside the wp_redirect() function.

As a result, when your plugin will be activated, it will automatically redirect to you to the specific location.

Answer (score 0):

***Use register_activation_hook(). Add this to your plugin.***

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'redirect_after_activation');

function cap_redirect_after_activation() {
    add_option('redirect_after_activation_option', true);
}

add_action('admin_init', 'plugin_activation_redirect');

function cap_plugin_activation_redirect() {
    if (get_option('redirect_after_activation_option', false)) {
        delete_option('redirect_after_activation_option');
        if(!isset($_GET['active-multi'])){
            wp_safe_redirect( admin_url('admin.php?page=cap') ); //your admin menu url 
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been tested my **[Best WP Testimonial](https://wordpress.org/plugins/best-wp-testimonial/)** and its working. Use  [register_activation_hook()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_activation_hook/) functions to do it.

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'bwpt_plugin_activate');
add_action('admin_init', 'bwpt_plugin_redirect');

function bwpt_plugin_activate() {
    add_option('bwpt_plugin_do_activation_redirect', true);
}

function bwpt_plugin_redirect() {
    if (get_option('bwpt_plugin_do_activation_redirect', false)) {
        delete_option('bwpt_plugin_do_activation_redirect');
        if(!isset($_GET['activate-multi']))
        {
            wp_redirect("edit.php?post_type=testimonial&page=bwpt-settings-page");
        }
    }
}
```